# How to unmerge or add a group name in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

In Crystal Reports, after adding a group, it's possible to add some text, and then add the group name to the text.

So, you start with

```
{Group #1}
```

You add some text:

```
Company Name:    {Group #1}
```

And then, you can drag the {Group #1} into the "Company Name:" text box, and it will display together (it makes the spacing nicer).

```
Company Name: {Group #1}
```

But that is now entirely a text field.  I need to use that group name elsewhere (in my totals).  How to I either unmerge that field so I have just {Group #1}, or else insert just the group name?

I can delete and re-add the group, but that undoes a lot of other work that I'd prefer not to have to re-do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula field and the do the same, here you can use formula field anywhere.

Create a formula field:

```
"Company Name:"+ {Group #1} //if Group1 is not string then convert using CSTR
```

Comment: Nice.  Thank you.